# Android Studio Emulator E/AudioFlinger error message

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

When I start any device from the AVD Manager it just loops this error message infinitely: 
`E/AudioFlinger: read failed: framesRead=-1`

It even does that when I create a new device. Doesn't matter if "Use Host GPU" is enabled or not.

When I start my application it would usually start up right after the emulated device started up. Since this error message appears it does not start my application automatically (the app can still be started manually though).

Anyone else had any experience with that and maybe a possible solution?

**EDIT 1**: It stops looping the error message as soon as i hit the app button. Seems to just occur on the home screen.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Open Google Settings app > Search & Now > Voice 
Here you need to turn off "OK Google" Detection. It may be grayed out and disabled with mark "Retrieving settings...". To make it enabled, just change the language to any other one in the field above it. If selected language is unsupported for "OK Google" detection, the switch inside this menu will be also grayed, it fixes the problem as well.

Comment: Worked for me on 6.0 API 23 x86_64 emulator

Comment: Settings > Google > Search & Now > Voice > "Ok Google" detection > From the Google app

Comment: On an old nexus 10" with Android 5.1.1 - 
Google Settings > Search > Voice > "OK google" detection

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem, and if I don't stop it, Logcat will "say" "Too much output!" and if I still don't stop it, I get prompts to send an error report to Google, even freezes.

I finally learned to put a strange set of characters that can't possibly be displayed by an error message (I use "~~~~~") and put the same string as the first argument of my `Log` statements and all I see are my own messages. Of course this means I don't see errors, especially `Exception`s, so I just put `Excep` after the string "~~~~~"  and delete them one by one (otherwise, here comes the deluge again).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

make sure you have audio permission in your manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. And besides my app does nothing audiowise so I do not want it to have RECORD_AUDIO permissions.